# What would generally be required to get an STC for swapping wing sections on a glider?

Tags: faa, aircraft-certification, stc

There are some neat gliders out there like the Pipistrel Sinus where the wing can be shortened/lengthened considerably by swapping out the outer wing panels.

[image]

If I wanted to do something similar and keep the glider's certification, i.e. not have it permanently be experimental, what would the FAA generally want to see? Since the plane has already received certification, it means that all flight safety and load limit tests are acceptable. If the new wing sections introduce no new controls, and the new Vne is less than or equal to the old Vne, then it would mean very little changes before/after aside from the percentage of loading on the inner section and the stall characteristics.

What's interesting here is that there are no airframe modifications required to swap out different wing sections. The operating equipment changes, i.e. different outboard wing sections, but that's it. Moreover, gliders have a special regulation which allows the pilot to assemble/disassemble wings as part of normal operation.

In my way of thinking, it would be as easy as showing the new wing section doesn't make for unsafe aerodynamics, that it's strong enough, and that the airplane has done the flight tests to show that it still handles within the required envelope. But that's way too easy, now isn't it?

What does the FAA want to see in these circumstances? Would an ultimate load test be required, or would only the new sections have to be tested to ultimate load (since we know the old sections already pass)?

(Obviously the right answer is to call the FSDO, but I'm more curious than serious.)